# Localization using dictionary

Tags: c++, localization

I'm trying to localize my application into other languages. For example, my application has a menu with the text "File". I'm using a dictionary to localize that into another language.

```
auto english = std::unordered_map<std::string, const char*>
(
{
          { "fileMenuText", "File" },
          { "editMenuText", "Edit" }
}
);
```

When I want to get the localized text for something, I just do this:

```
const char* text = english.at("fileMenuText");
```

The only issue is, I'm worried that this will be slow, or it is not a good way to do this.

Also, is there a way to handle formatting? For example, `printf`

Is there any other cross-platform way to do this?

Comment: There is several libraries which handle i18n (including plural rules).

Comment: Translation is done at init of "widget "or for user interaction, it should not be noticeable.

Comment: Yeah, I know. At the start of the application I will load the translation table.

Comment: formatting as `%s` is regular text. Just that as runtime string for format doesn't allow compiler to check conformance between format and passed parameters.

Comment: I meant, the translation itself: showing the menu. the `english.at("fileMenuText");`.

Comment: What do you mean? At runtime I just grab the values from the dictionary.

Comment: *"I'm worried that this will be slow"*. At which stage? creation of the map? or at translation? my comment was for the later. For the former, I suspect  that it would be negligible against parsing the dictionary.